# Prestashop admin page open on IE and reloads on Chrome

Tags: content-management-system, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I just installed a new theme working on Prestashop 1.7.4.2 using the quickstart installation in order to get the demo content. After a succesful installation, the admin page didn't want to connect on chrome, it only reloads the same page when i log in. But it works fine on Internet Explorer and also on my phone.
PhP version is 7.3, can anyone please elaborate on this?
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to clear the cookies in your Chrome browser? You might also want to try the incognito mode

Comment: Hey Krystian, thanks for your reply, indeed i cleared all the cookies and tried incognito mode without any success!